# Renewal Process with Pareto distributed inter-arrival time

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform

I am analyzing a renewal process $N(t)$ whose inter arrival time $t$ conforms to the Pareto distribution, the PDF $f(t)$ of the Pareto distribution is as follows:

$$f(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
\frac{{\alpha {k^\alpha }}}{{{t^{\alpha  + 1}}}},&t > k\\
0,&t < k
\end{array} \right.$$
where $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, $k$ is the scale parameter ($\alpha>0,k>0$).

The CDF $F(t)$ is:

$$F(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr}
1 - {\left( {\frac{k}{t}} \right)^\alpha },&t > k\\
0,&t < k
\end{array} \right.$$

Let $m(t)=E[N(t)]$, $m(t)$ is referred to as the `renewal function`, and let $\tilde{m}(s)$ denote the Laplace-Stieltjes Transform (LST) of $m(t)$, so
$$\tilde{m}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\mathrm dm(t)$$

It's well known that $m(s)$ satisfies the following equation (the LST of the `renewal equation`):

$$\tilde{m}(s)=\frac{\tilde{F}(s)}{1-\tilde{F}(s)}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
where $\tilde{F}(s)$ is the LST of $F(t)$, i.e., $\tilde{F}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\mathrm dF(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\mathrm dt$.

Here comes the question, actually the LST of $F(t)$ does not exist due to the $\frac{1}{t^{\alpha+1}}$ form in $f(t)$. So how can I compute $\tilde{m}(s)$ according to Formula (1)?

I have been stuck on this question for several days, your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @Did Could you please have a look at this?

Comment: Of course the Laplace transform of F exists, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Did By `does not exist` I mean the Laplace transform of F(t) does not have a rational expression. The Laplace transform of F(t) can be expressed by the incomplete Gamma function, but it is in the form of integral, but not a polynomial or exponential.